# Appropriate words for packages

Tags: word-request

I am looking for some appropriate words for packages.
I tried looking for images in the web but could not find anything. Have you ever seen these large strings of candy or cookies packages attached one to another. You can buy the whole string or rip one package and buy only one (or two or three).

Anyway, I am looking for appropriate words (and if I can't find them,  phrases) to describe these two concepts: 1) A single package and 2) a string of these packages

Specially the second one, I can have several of these strings and count them, so it has to clearly denote this attached series of packages.

EDIT:
I looked harder for an image and I could find something. Take a look:
[image]

You see there are four packages of candy attached to each other. 
How to call one of these attached strings , and how to call each of the four components...

EDIT2:
How about "packages" and "packets"??
As in "A package has n packets"

Answer (score 1):

I call it a *sachet.* That is the *single* pack of whatever material it has.

For the *string* you mention, I know a word - *a strip.* Strip packets are the string or entire row of sachets.

[One such example is here.](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Fleischmanns-Rapid-Rise-Instant-Yeast-3-Strip-Packets-Fast-Acting-Buy-4-Get-1-/302157426160)

I tell the same to shopkeepers at times:

> Ah, get me the entire *strip, not just a sachet!*

For the Edit 2: A strip has *n* sachets.

Comment: Sachet would not be common in North American English daily usage (though it might appear in legal or technical packaging descriptions). "Packet" would probably be most common.

Answer (score 0):

British and Australian English use the term "outer" to refer to a package of retail units smaller than a carton.

In this case I think the better word is "strip".